# Turn off reformat for a specific language in Android Studio (IDEA)

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

Problem comes from iOS code (KMM).
`#if DEBUG ... #endif` in iOS code cases Android Studio to detect the file as C++ file because of this code. As a result, if "Reformat code" option is enabled, this file become formatted in a very bad way (even, not compilable way).
Any suggestions to solve the problem and not turn off the "Reformat"?

Comment: You don't want to disable the formatter, you want the IDE to recognize the file type correctly. It's more likely an extension association than anything related to the comment style. Look for a setting page called "file associations" and see if you can change it to use the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions, that I found and using is set in `Do not format` value `*.swift`.
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Formatter

Or in .idea/CodeStyles/Project.xml:

```
    <option name="DO_NOT_FORMAT">
      <list>
        <fileSet type="globPattern" pattern="*.swift" />
      </list>
    </option>
```